# Calling Object using jQote jQuery

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, jqote

I am using jQote library for javascript template
the follow is my **JSON** response from ajax request

```
{"Person":[{"actor_image":"Image1","actor":"Name1"}]}
```

**the following is the jQuery code**

```
$(document).on('click',".notifications",function(){    
    $("#notificationRegionWrapper").toggle();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/async/getnotificationfeed",
        dataType: 'json',
        async:false,
        success: function(res) {
            var dataJson = $.parseJSON(res);
            $('#users').jqotesub('#template', dataJson);
        }
    });   
});
```

and here I am trying to out the Object but an error is giving for me 

**this.Person is undefined**

this how i am trying to out put the object because i want to iterate over the object

```
<table id="users">

</table>
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <![CDATA[
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><%=  this.Person.length %></td>
        </tr>
    ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worked after I removed

```
 var dataJson = $.parseJSON(res);
```

and edited the jQote function to :

```
 $('#users').jqotesub('#template', res);
```